# Timeout on Profile Deletions

Tags: support, network-profile

I was going through and cleaning up my network profiles. I removed the link from a couple of them and then noticed the link was not there after the third or fourth.

Is there a time limit on how many you can delete a profile from in a given period? It's been several minutes and I still can't remove them at all.

[image: menu where the deletion option was]

Comment: You cannot directly delete an account on a site where you have voted or posted. See the help center article on [account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) for what to do.

Comment: Gotcha. I looked down the list a few items and noticed that there were some others that allowed it shortly after I posted. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Posting _more than once_ blocks instant self-deletion; posting once does not.